# Eloquent retrieve updated_at after update

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new with Laravel/Lumen and ORM.
I've got this operation on the database:

```
$items = Item::where('id', $this->id)
    ->where('is_shown', 1);       
    ->update([
            'is_shown' => 0,
        ]);
```

How I can retrieve `updated_at` column value after update operation without additional query?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$items->updated_at;
```

You can see all the properties of the object with

```
dd($items);
```

Update:
try:

```
$items = Item::whereId($this->id)->whereIsShown(0)->get();
foreach($items as $item){
   dump($item);
}
```

Comment: @mihai After the update() call $items is the number of rows updated and not a object. I get: `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: A better and correct way to approach this issue can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625247/laravel-get-record-id-from-update-query You can also check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093965/return-collection-after-update