# Laravel Get Record ID from Update Query

Tags: mysql, laravel

For this update query, I'm trying to get the id after I run it.

```
$results = DB::table('testDB123.users')
    ->where('fbID', '=', $x['id'])
    ->update([
            'updated_at' => $x['currDate'],
            'fbFirstName' => $x['firstName'],
            'fbLastName' => $x['lastName']
        ]
    );
```

Tried this with no luck `$results->id`

Is there anything similar to `insertGetId` for update queries?

```
$id = DB::table($table1)->insertGetId([...])
```

Answer (score 10):

`update()` method doesn't return an object, so you have two options:

**Option 1**

Use `updateOrCreate()`:

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate(['fbID' => $x['id']], $dataArray);
$id = $user->id;
```

**Option 2**

Get an object and update it:

```
$user = User::where('fbID', '=', $x['id'])->first();
$user->update($dataArray);

$id = $user->id;
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you. 