# Return Collection after update()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Using Raw, how to return collection of updated row?

For example:

```
$updated = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->update(['votes' => 123]);
```

I was expecting `dd($updated)` to return updated row of collection but it returned 1.

```
{{$updated->votes}} should return 123
```

Comment: Updated is the no. of rows updated by this query

Comment: You gonna have to select the row after update statement

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not how it works. You can't expect this query will return you an object:

```
$updated = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->update(['votes' => 123]);
```

If you want to use Query Builder only as you mentioned in your question, you'll need to get an object manually:

```
$data = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

With Eloquent you can use the `updateOrCreate()`:

```
$data = User::where('id', 1)->updateOrCreate(['votes' => 123]);
```

This will return an object. `update()` will return boolean, so you can't use it here.

Comment: huh. `updateOrCreate()` doesn't seem to work that way per their [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) or [implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L488-L500). did that work in a super old version?

Comment: updateOrCreate() works for me thanks :)

Answer (score 40):

Try this

```
$updated = tap(DB::table('users')->where('id', 1))
    ->update(['votes' => 123])
    ->first();
```

Comment: The best answer!

Comment: This is it! THX

Comment: Simplest and best answer, can you tell, what Tap() function do here ?

Comment: laravel not working in orm :(

Comment: Laravel 8.* working.

Comment: Really a good solution :)

Comment: @Qazi The tap method is typically used for executing a callback on a value, but it doesn't return the modified value. If you want to retrieve the updated user record, you should use first after the update method.

Answer (score 9):

for version 6: another way with eloquent to return the new updated model by chaining the update method call through tap :

```
$user = tap($user)->update(['votes' => 123]);
```

Comment: Doing this in laravel 7, I get the model instance of before the update and not after

Comment: it was working with laravel 6, I am gonna update the answer to limit the answer for version 6

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with Eloquent ORM

```
tap(User::findOrFail(1))->update(["votes" => 123]);
```

tap is a simple PHP function that basically does:

```
function tap($value, $callback)
{
   $callback($value);

   return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also returns the updated row:

```php
$user = $user->fill(['votes' => 123])->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me:

```
$updated = DB::select("UPDATE users SET votes = 123 WHERE id = 1 RETURNING votes");
```

Then, since `select` returns an array: `$votes = $updated[0]->votes;`

And I believe you could even retrieve the entire row(s) using `RETURNING *`

This also work with prepared statements:

```
$updated = DB::select("UPDATE users SET votes = ? WHERE id = ? RETURNING votes", [$votes, $id]);
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I am using a Postgres database. This will work only on a db that supports such a thing as `RETURNING`

Answer (score -1):

> you get the first row again after update see example bellow

```
$user = User::where('id', 1);
$userOld = $user->first(); // will return the first row
$isUserUpdated = $user->update(['name'=>'new name']); // will return true or false 
$updatedUser = $user->first(); // now it will return you the latest updated data
```

> by this example you have old data and new data and is data updated result, now we can return new data.

```
return response()->json(['status' => $isUserUpdated,'data'=>$updatedUser], 200);
```

Comment: Its working for me, nicely.

Answer (score -12):

**In controller you write below code for update :**

```
 $updated = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->update(['votes' => 123])->get();
```

Comment: update() returns an integer, not a query builder object